# How to extract pushed nodes from Firebase Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating interview slots in Firebase using the following code:

```
String user_id=userauth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference current_user_db=mDatabase.child("Users").child(user_id);
                        current_user_db.setValue(user);

                        intervw_slots.add(b.getInterview_slotpref1());
                        intervw_slots.add(b.getInterview_slotpref2());
                        intervw_slots.add(b.getInterview_slotpref3());
                        intervw_slots.add(b.getInterview_slotpref4());
                        intervw_slots.add(b.getInterview_slotpref5());

                        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
                            interview_slots = mDatabase.child("Interview Slots").child(intervw_slots.get(i));
                            interview_slots.push().setValue(user.getEmail());
                            //interview_slots.setValue(true);
                        }
```

So this gives me all userid/emails under each interview slot in hierarchical format.
My database structure is:

```
>Interview_slots
>>Dec 20: 11 PM
>>>>-KZGl9nWJ9PPtVD_rRlG:abc@gmail.com
>>>>-KZGlSw3B5lvr2EeLNzC:xyz@gmail.com
>>Dec 21: 9 PM
>>>>-KZGl9nWJ9PPtVD_rRlG:mn@gmail.com
>>>>-KZGlSw3B5lvr2EeLNzC:pq@gmail.com
```

**I want to retrieve and print all email ids under a particular interview slot.(preferably send an email to each email through firebase)** Please note that I have created interview slot nodes by not one variable, but by using array.

Comment: I can't understand your question, please include the database structure in text format (not screenshot), you can easily export the database by choosing "Export JSON" from the firebase database console's menu. You can remove any sensitive information.

Comment: Edited the comment @Wilik. Please help me.

Comment: have you tried reading [this guide on how to retrieve list of data on android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data) ? if yes, please tell us your problem and show the code.